# Scrapy dupefilter filtering redirects even with dont_filter=True

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to scrape a page that redirects me a few times to itself (bouncing between http and https) before finally responding:

```
2020-11-06 11:24:38 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2020-11-06 11:24:38 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET https://www.example.com/some/page.htm> from <GET http://www.example.com/some/page.htm>
2020-11-06 11:24:38 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET http://www.example.com/some/sample/path> from <GET https://www.example.com/some/page.htm>
2020-11-06 11:24:39 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET https://www.example.com/some/sample/path> from <GET http://www.example.com/some/sample/path>
2020-11-06 11:24:39 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (301) to <GET http://www.example.com/some/sample/path/> from <GET https://www.example.com/some/sample/path>
2020-11-06 11:24:39 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET https://www.example.com/some/sample/path/> from <GET http://www.example.com/some/sample/path/>
2020-11-06 11:24:39 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.example.com/some/sample/path/> (referer: None)
```

As you can see in the logs, the source page redirects me to a secondary page that redirects to the same page but with http, then it redirects to https and so on. **Finally it works, but only when I'm using** `scrapy shell`, in the spider this get's filtered. Here are the spider's logs:

```
2020-11-06 11:40:14 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET https://www.example.com/some/page.htm>> from <GET http://www.example.com/some/page.htm>
2020-11-06 11:40:14 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET http://www.example.com/some/sample/path> from <GET https://www.example.com/some/page.htm>>
2020-11-06 11:40:15 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET https://www.example.com/some/sample/path> from <GET http://www.example.com/some/sample/path>
2020-11-06 11:40:15 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (301) to <GET http://www.example.com/some/sample/path/> from <GET https://www.example.com/some/sample/path>
2020-11-06 11:40:15 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET https://www.example.com/some/sample/path/> from <GET http://www.example.com/some/sample/path/>
2020-11-06 11:40:15 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.example.com/some/sample/path/> (referer: None)
2020-11-06 11:40:15 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.example.com/some/sample/path/> (referer: https://www.example.com/some/sample/path/)
2020-11-06 11:40:16 [scrapy.dupefilters] DEBUG: Filtered duplicate request: <GET https://www.example.com/some/sample/path/> (referer: https://www.example.com/some/sample/path/)
```

That happens even if the request is made with `dont_filter=True`

```
start_urls = ['http://www.example.com/some/page.htm']

def start_requests(self):
    for url in self.start_urls:
        yield Request(url, dont_filter=True)
```

I've tried to use `dont_redirect=True`, but that just causes the spider to close, as it doesn't receive a response.

I don't know why the server does that, but more important is how can prevent scrapy from filtering the redirects?

Comment: With `dont_filter=True` it should not happen. You say it does, but I’m having a hard time believing that :). Without it, it happens due to a known issue: https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/1225

Comment: I understand your skepticism and I'm sorry I cant provide a MVE, but if `dont_filter=True` prevented the issue I would have it solved already :). That snippet up there is a copy and paste of the spider's code, only changed the URL. Interesting enough, using `custom_settings = {'DUPEFILTER_CLASS': 'scrapy.dupefilters.BaseDupeFilter'}` prevents the filtering, but get's me in an infinite redirecting loop. However when using `scrapy shell` that doesn't happen.

Comment: What’s the problem to provide a reproducible example? Maybe you could use http://httpbin.org/#/Redirects or similar to avoid exposing the actual target URL.